# How do you get all the rows from a particular table using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am learning Python and BeautifulSoup to scrape data from the web, and read a HTML table. I can read it into Open Office and it says that it is Table #11.

It seems like BeautifulSoup is the preferred choice, but can anyone tell me how to grab a particular table and all the rows? I have looked at the module documentation, but can't get my head around it. Many of the examples that I have found online appear to do more than I need.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

This should be pretty straight forward if you have a chunk of HTML to parse with BeautifulSoup. The general idea is to navigate to your table using the `findChildren` method, then you can get the text value inside the cell with the `string` property.

```
>>> from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
>>> 
>>> html = """
... <html>
... <body>
...     <table>
...         <th><td>column 1</td><td>column 2</td></th>
...         <tr><td>value 1</td><td>value 2</td></tr>
...     </table>
... </body>
... </html>
... """
>>>
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
>>> tables = soup.findChildren('table')
>>>
>>> # This will get the first (and only) table. Your page may have more.
>>> my_table = tables[0]
>>>
>>> # You can find children with multiple tags by passing a list of strings
>>> rows = my_table.findChildren(['th', 'tr'])
>>>
>>> for row in rows:
...     cells = row.findChildren('td')
...     for cell in cells:
...         value = cell.string
...         print("The value in this cell is %s" % value)
... 
The value in this cell is column 1
The value in this cell is column 2
The value in this cell is value 1
The value in this cell is value 2
>>>
```

Comment: That was the trick! Code worked and I should be able to modify it as needed.  Many thanks.  One last question.  I can follow the code except for when you search the table for children th and tr.  Is that simply searching my table and returning both the table header and table rows?  If I only wanted the table rows, I simply could search for tr only?  

many thanks again!

Comment: Yes, `.findChildren(['th', 'tr'])` is searching for elements with tag type of `th` or `tr`. If you just want to find `tr` elements you would use `.findChildren('tr')` (note not a list, just the string)

Comment: It's also worthwhile to note that [PyQuery](https://pythonhosted.org/pyquery/api.html) is a really really nice alternative to BeautifulSoup.

Comment: `th` is a header cell. This is a malformed table.

Answer (score 5):

If you ever have nested tables (as on the old-school designed websites), the above approach might fail.

As a solution, you might want to extract non-nested tables first:

```
html = '''<table>
<tr>
<td>Top level table cell</td>
<td>
    <table>
    <tr><td>Nested table cell</td></tr>
    <tr><td>...another nested cell</td></tr>
    </table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
non_nested_tables = [t for t in soup.find_all('table') if not t.find_all('table')]
```

Alternatively, if you want to extract content of all the tables, including those that nest other tables, you can extract only top-level `tr` and `th`/`td` headers. For this, you need to turn off recursion when calling the `find_all` method:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
tables = soup.find_all('table')
cnt = 0
for my_table in tables:
    cnt += 1
    print ('=============== TABLE {} ==============='.format(cnt))
    rows = my_table.find_all('tr', recursive=False)                  # <-- HERE
    for row in rows:
        cells = row.find_all(['th', 'td'], recursive=False)          # <-- HERE
        for cell in cells:
            # DO SOMETHING
            if cell.string: print (cell.string)
```

Output:

```
=============== TABLE 1 ===============
Top level table cell
=============== TABLE 2 ===============
Nested table cell
...another nested cell
```

Answer (score 0):

The recursive is a great trick if you don't have nested tables, but if you do, then you need to do things one level at a time.

The one HTML variation that could bite you is the following where the tbody and or thead elements are also used.

```
html = '
    <table class="fancy">
        <thead>
           <tr><th>Nested table cell</th></tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr><td><table id=2>...another nested cell</table></td></tr>
        </tbody> 
        </table>
    </table>
```

in this situation, you will need to do the following

```
   table = soup.find_all("table", {"class": "fancy"})[0]
    thead = table.find_all('thead', recursive=False)
    header = thead[0].findChildren('th')
    
    tbody = table.find_all('tbody', recursive=False)
    rows = tbody[0].find_all('tr', recursive=False)
```

now you have the head and rows