# How can parse through the given link in python to obtain the company name and the symbol from yahoo finance?

Tags: python-2.7, yahoo-finance

I want to parse in the following 2 links given as http://in.finance.yahoo.com/gainers?e=bo and http://in.finance.yahoo.com/losers?e=bo (Gainers and Losers).

Can lxml be used or some other python module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you could certainly use something like lxml, or beautiful soup.

An example of the latter can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010481/how-do-you-get-all-the-rows-from-a-particular-table-using-beautifulsoup).

Answer (score 0):

I would think that your best bet would be [scrapy](http://scrapy.org/).  Since it is specifically aimed at scraping web sites it should be quiet simple to do if you look at the documentation.