# beautifulsoup query in python3.6

Tags: beautifulsoup, python-3.6

i am very new to python and beautifulSoup too..i am leaning web scraping from ryan mtichell book.
website i am scraping is http://www.pythonscraping.com/pages/page3.html

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
html = urlopen("http://www.pythonscraping.com/pages/page3.html")
bs0bj = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
for i in bs0bj.find_all(id="gift1"):
    print(i.get_text())

#for i in bs0bj.find_all("tr", {"class":"gift"}):
#    print(i)
 #   for c in bs0bj.find_all("img", {"src":re.compile(\.\.\/img\/gifts/img.*\.jpg)}):
  #      print(c.image["src"])
```

my question is i want to scrap only 1 row of gift item header("item, descripion, cost, image) along with image name like...img/gift.jpg but till i am unable to do som can someone please help me to write the correct code

and also please explain the codes so that i can understand it too...without tags

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you get all the rows from a particular table using BeautifulSoup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010481/how-do-you-get-all-the-rows-from-a-particular-table-using-beautifulsoup)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you were looking for?

```
for i in bs0bj.find_all(id="gift1"):
    print(i.get_text())
    print(i.img.get('src'))
```

Comment: print(i.img.get('src')), if you can explain get here? please and what if i want every row with every image?

Comment: @Prince You specified in the for loop to search through the elements in the tr element with id="gift1", we call get on the img element and ask to fetch the text contained in the src attribute.

Similarly, if you want to print out every row with every image the for loop becomes:

`for i in bs0bj.find_all(class_="gift"):`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
html = urlopen("http://www.pythonscraping.com/pages/page3.html")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
my_table =soup.find_all("table",id="giftList")
my_table =my_table[0]
rows = my_table.findChildren(['th', 'tr'])
for row in rows:
    cells = row.findChildren('td')
    for cell in cells:
        value = cell.string
        print ("The value in this cell is %s" % value)
```

There is a lot of help online, that you can check.

Comment: Thank you so much sir for you help. i really learned a lot from your codes

Comment: @PrinceBhatia, Welcome. Dont forget to accept the answer and vote