# Fetching <td> text next to <th> tag with specific text

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'd linke to retrieve information form a couple of players from [transfermarkt.de](https://www.transfermarkt.de), e.g [Manuel Neuer's](https://www.transfermarkt.de/manuel-neuer/profil/spieler/17259) birthday.
Here is how the relevant html looks like:

```
<tr>
    <th>Geburtsdatum:</th>
    <td>
        <a href="/aktuell/waspassiertheute/aktuell/new/datum/1986-03-27">27.03.1986</a>                                     
    </td>
</tr>
```

I know I could get the date by using the following code:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(source_code, "html.parser")
player_attributes = soup.find("table", class_ = 'auflistung')
rows = player_attributes.find_all('tr')
date_of_birth = re.search(r'([0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)', rows[1].get_text(), re.M)[0]
```

but that is quite fragile. E.g. for [Robert Lewandowski](https://www.transfermarkt.de/robert-lewandowski/profil/spieler/38253) the date of birth is in a different position of the table. So, which attributes appear at the players profile differs. Is there a way to logically do

- finde the  tag with 'Geburtsdatum:' in it
- get the text of the  tag right after it

the more robust the better :)

Comment: Get the whole table, then go row by row check where `row = birthday`  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010481/how-do-you-get-all-the-rows-from-a-particular-table-using-beautifulsoup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BeautifulSoup allows retrieve next sibling using method `findNext()`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

html = requests.get('https://www.transfermarkt.de/manuel-neuer/profil/spieler/17259', headers = {'User-Agent': 'Custom'})
soup = BeautifulSoup(source_code, "html.parser") 
player_attributes = soup.find("table", class_ = 'auflistung') 
rows = player_attributes.find_all('tr') 

def get_table_value(rows, table_header):
    for row in rows:
        helpers = row.find_all(text=re.compile(table_header))
        if helpers is not None:
            for helper in helpers:
                return helper.find_next('td').get_text()
```

Comment: Thanks, that almost solved my problem :). Here is what finally did the job:
 `soup = BeautifulSoup(source_code, "html.parser")
player_attributes = soup.find("table", class_ = 'auflistung')
rows = player_attributes.find_all('tr')
def get_table_value(rows, table_header):    
    for row in rows:
        helpers = row.find_all(text=re.compile(table_header))
        if helpers is not None:
            for helper in helpers:
                return helper.find_next('td').get_text()`

Comment: could you add my solution to your answer for people checking it later?