# Why do only the first two rows of html table from web page get read?

Tags: python, html, pandas, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape data from an html table on a web page. I've tried a few different methods based on answers posted here, but always getting a problem: the result is roughly what I expect but only for the first two rows of the table. I have little experience with html and beautiful soup, but from the html file of the table in the url I can't see any difference between the first two rows and the rest of the table. Could anyone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

```
import numpy
import pandas as pd
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://www.astronomy.ohio-state.edu/asassn/transients.html'

# First method
source = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(source,'lxml')
table = soup.find('table')
table_rows = table.find_all('tr')

for tr in table_rows:
    print(tr)

>>>(prints html text for first two rows)


# Second method
html = requests.get(url).content
df_list = pd.read_html(html)
df = df_list[-1]
print (df)

>>> ASAS-SN Other ATEL  RA  Dec  ...   SDSS    DSS Vizier Spectroscopic Class Comments
0      ID   IDs  TNS NaN  NaN  ...  image  image   data                 NaN      NaN

[1 rows x 12 columns]
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010481/how-do-you-get-all-the-rows-from-a-particular-table-using-beautifulsoup is a good introduction.

Comment: first you could `print(html)` and `print(source)` to see if server sends you full HTML. Next you can try different parser `BeautifulSoup(... , 'html.parser')` or `BeautifulSoup(... , 'html5lib')` because table may have some mistakes in HTML and some parsers may not read incorrect HTML.

Comment: BTW: pandas can read directly from url - `pd.read_html(url)`

Comment: I get all rows with `BeautifulSoup(source, 'html5lib')`

Comment: Thanks, this worked!!

Comment: If you would like to post this as an answer I will accept it as the solution. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes people create incorrect HTML but web browsers may display this correctly because there don't respect strictly all rules.

`BeautifulSoup` can use three different parsers - `lxml`, `html.parser` and `html5lib` and they may parse broken HTML in different way.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'html.parser')
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'html5lib')
```

It seems `lxml` skips wrong elements and you get only two rows but `html5lib` can parse incorrect elements and gives all rows.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'html5lib')
```

---

**BTW:**

In `BeautifulSoup` documentation in section [installing a parser](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser) you can see table with comparition of these parsers (advantages/disadvantages).

People may use `lxml` because it uses code in C/C++ so it can works faster.

---

**BTW:**

`pandas` can read HTML table directly from `url`

```
read_html(url)
```

In [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html) you can see that it uses `lxml` as default parser but you may change it to `bs4+html5lib`

```
read_html(html, flavor="bs4")

read_html(url, flavor="bs4")
```

or

```
read_html(html, flavor="html5lib")

read_html(url, flavor="html5lib")
```

I tested it and `flavor="html5lib"` gives all rows.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out, it worked for me.

```
import requests
url = 'http://www.astronomy.ohio-state.edu/asassn/transients.html'
df_list = pd.read_html(url, header=0, flavor='bs4')
df = df_list[0]
print (df)
```

Answer (score -2):

I think the problem here is the index. Try this code for the second method

```
html = requests.get(url).content
df_list = pd.read_html(html, header=0)
df = df_list[0]
print (df)
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately this gave me the same result