# Python Pandas : Getting only 3 first elements from table

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping

I using pandas to webscrape this site https://www.mapsofworld.com/lat_long/poland-lat-long.html but i only gettin 3 elements. How could I get all elements from table?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

#for getting world map
import folium

# Retreiving Latitude and Longitude coordinates
info = pd.read_html("https://www.mapsofworld.com/lat_long/poland-lat-long.html",match='Augustow',skiprows=2)

#convering the table data into DataFrame
coordinates = pd.DataFrame(info[0])
data = coordinates.head()

print(data)
```

[image: pick]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like if you install and [use `html5lib` as your parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65288453/why-do-only-the-first-two-rows-of-html-table-from-web-page-get-read) it may fix your issues:

```py
df = pd.read_html("https://www.mapsofworld.com/lat_long/poland-lat-long.html",attrs={"class":"tableizer-table"},skiprows=2,flavor="html5lib")

>>>df
[                      0         1          2
0             Locations  Latitude  Longitude
1                   NaN       NaN        NaN
2              Augustow   53°51'N    23°00'E
3    Auschwitz/Oswiecim   50°02'N    19°11'E
4       Biala Podxlaska   52°04'N    23°06'E
..                  ...       ...        ...
177           Zawiercie   50°30'N    19°24'E
178        Zdunska Wola   51°37'N    18°59'E
179           Zgorzelec   51°10'N     15°0'E
180            Zyrardow    52°3'N    20°28'E
181              Zywiec   49°42'N    19°10'E

[182 rows x 3 columns]]
```

Comment: Ok i tried it but its the same out with one element

Comment: same output as well with info

Comment: *edited to reference other SO question with possible answer

Comment: Yeah it works thank you so umch for you effort :)